# For $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$, the sequence $(f_n(x, \cdot))_n$ is Cauchy in $L^1 (Y)$. Then $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $L^1 (X \times Y)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$ be complete $\sigma$-finite measure spaces,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $\mathcal C :=\mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B$ the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$,
- $\lambda := \mu \otimes \nu$ the product measure of $\mu$ and $\nu$.

*Theorem 4.4.1* at page 98 of Martin Väth's monograph [Ideal Spaces](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0093548) suggests that

> **Theorem** Let $\mu, \nu$ be finite measures, i.e., $\mu(X) + \nu (Y)< \infty$. Let $f_n:X \times Y \to E$ be $\lambda$-simple for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Assume that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$, the sequence $(f_n(x, \cdot))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^1 (Y)$. Then $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^1 (X \times Y)$.

The author's proof is in the context of pre-ideal spaces, which is unfamiliar to me. Here I work with the usual Bochner spaces.

> Could you elaborate on how to prove above **Theorem**?

---

Below I add relevant paragraph in the book.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sure about the hypotheses? I do not even believe that they imply $f_n\in L^1(X\times Y)$.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth It's possible that I mis-understood the paragraphs in the book, so I have added the screenshots of the relevant ones. I think the correct hypothesis is that $f_n$ is $\lambda$-simple rather than just $\lambda$-measurable. Please have a check on my update.

Comment: Apparently, Väth only claims that $y_n$ is Cauchy in the space of measurable functions with the (completely metrizable) topology of **convergence in measure** (which is given by the metric $d(y,z)=\int \min\{|y-z|,1\}d\mu$).

Comment: @JochenWengenroth From [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Properties) Wikipedia page, there is a result *If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite and $\left(f_n\right)$ converges (locally or globally) to $f$ in measure, there is a subsequence converging to $f$ almost everywhere*. So you explanation makes a lot of sense. Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Väth only claims that the sequence $y_n$ is Cauchy in the space of measurable functions with the topology (or rather, uniformity) of convergence in measure which, for finite measures, is given by the complete (semi- or pseudo-) metric $d(y,z)=\int\min\{|y-z|,1\} d\mu$. A sequence $y_n$ converges to $y$ if and only if $\mu(|y_n-y|>\varepsilon)\to 0$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ if and only if every subsequence $n(k)$ has a further subsequence such that $y_{n(k(\ell))}\to y$ $\mu$-a.s.